# Web приложение для поиска файлов

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, jsp

Есть класс Find.java для поиска  всех файлов в папках и подпапках. Также имеется две jsp страницы, index и secondpage. На странице index.jsp есть поле, чтобы ввести путь папки. На странице secondpage.jsp должен выводиться список всех файлов. Не понимаю как передать параметр  для класса? (И вообще запутался).

Java.class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;


public class Find {
  public  File folder = new File("");
  static String temp = "";

  private String text;

  public void setText(String text) {
         this.text = text;
  }

  public List<String> getList() {
         return null;
  }

  public  void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Reading files under the folder "+ folder.getAbsolutePath());
    listFilesForFolder(folder);
  }

  public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
      if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        // System.out.println("Поиск в папках "+folder.getAbsolutePath());
        listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
      } else {
        if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
          temp = fileEntry.getName();
         // if ((temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, temp.length()).toLowerCase()).equals("txt"))
            System.out.println("File= " + folder.getAbsolutePath()+ "\\" + fileEntry.getName());
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

index.jsp

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page language="java"
       contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>mainpage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<center>FileFinder</center>
<br>
       <form action="secondpage.jsp" method="POST" >
       Поиск:  <input type="text" name="text" value="">
       </form>
</body>
</html>
```

secondpage.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@page import="ru.getCardInfo.Find"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <%
Find find = new Find();;
String name = request.getParameter("text");
System.out.print(name);
  %>
<html>
<head>
<title>secondpage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="Find" scope="session" class="ru.getCardInfo.Find" />
  <jsp:setProperty name="text" property="text" value='<%= name %>' />
       <input type="text" value='<jsp:getProperty name="Find" property="text" />' readonly />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Павел,

Действительно сумбурно у Вас все выглядит. На быструю руку перебил то, что Вы сделали.

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>mainpage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<center>FileFinder</center>
<br/>
<form action="secondpage.jsp" method="POST">
    Поиск: <input type="text" name="text" value=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**secondpage.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="servlets.Find" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>secondpage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<%
    String path = request.getParameter("text");
    List<String> files = new Find().listFilesForFolder(path);
    request.setAttribute("listOfFiles", files);
%>

<table>
    <c:forEach items="${listOfFiles}" var="file">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${file}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<form action="secondpage.jsp" method="POST">
    Поиск: <input type="text" name="text" value=""/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Find.java**

```
package servlets;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Find {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> listFilesForFolder(String path) {
        File folder = new File(path);
        for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
                    result.add(folder.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileEntry.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

И не забудьте добавить `jstl-1.2.jar` в `WEB-INF\lib`.

Результат будет выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этого должно хватить, чтобы из этого Вы смогли сделать Ваше идеальное решение. Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, работает